# Xamarin iOS SslStream.AuthenticateAsUser() returns exception "Unknown Secure Transport error `PeerHandshakeFail'."

Tags: c#, xamarin, tls1.2, .net-standard, sslstream

I'm working on a Xamarin application where i'm establishing a connection with a Server. The server code is currently a blackbox for me, i only have the documentation.

However, since the server switched to TLS1.2 i'm trying use .NET's SslStream to authenticate on my app. I made sure that both are using the same certificate. The **certificate is selfsigned** though.

Whenever i try to do AuthenticateAsClient i get the following exception:

```
Mono.Security.Interface.TlsException: Unknown Secure Transport error `PeerHandshakeFail'.
```

Here's some part of my code:

```
using (var stream = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(mainSocket), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate)))
{
   try
   {
       stream.AuthenticateAsClient(ServerIpAdressServer, GetX509CertificateCollection(), System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(e);
   }
}
```

(The ValidateServerCertificate always returns true)

Here's my method to get the certificate:

```
public static X509CertificateCollection GetX509CertificateCollection()
{
    var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MyClass)).Assembly;
    X509CertificateCollection collection1;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("namespace.cert.pem").CopyTo(ms);
        X509Certificate2 certificate1 = new X509Certificate2(ms.ToArray());
        collection1 = new X509CertificateCollection();
        collection1.Add(certificate1);
    }
    return collection1;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps the client is not compatible with server in TLS1.2 .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Do you know if there's any reason for that? Usually xamarin iOS should be compatible with TLS1.2, right?

Comment: Okey, I have shared an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Warning in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/http-stack?context=xamarin/cross-platform) about TLS1.2 in Xamarin IOS.May be helpful for you.

> the downside is that it requires the event loop to be running for async operations to be executed.

[SslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasclientasync?view=netframework-4.8) : Authenticate the client side of a client-server connection as an asynchronous operation.

So from your testing with async method ,this is the right solution. Glad solved it.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far! My proeject is running on the latest version of Xamarin.iOS and Forms. I also set the HttpClient Implementation to `NSUrlSession`.
What i realized though is, that in the article it says, that the downside of TLS1.2 is that operations need to be operated async. So maybe i need to use `AuthenticateAsClientAsync()` if i use TLS1.2?

Comment: @EliasJohannes You can try AuthenticateAsClientAsync . If not works , have a try this:Under "Project Options > iOS Build", change the "SSL/TLS implementation" setting back to the old default "Mono (TLS v1.0)". If be helpful , thanks for marking in advance.

Comment: I really got it working by using the async authenticate method. Your link brought me on the right path. If you want you can edit your answer so i can mark it as accepted

Comment: @EliasJohannes Okey, Glad this works. I have updated answer , and thanks for replying and marking in advance  :)